# RoR Apply multiple filtering options while remembering all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an events page with two distinct filtering options. One filters by 'period', the other by 'tag'.

The `period` filter is performed via a GET request and the `tag` filter uses a form to POST its value.

The defined routes for `events`:

```
resources :events
post 'tags/(:tag)', to: 'events#index', as: :tag
get 'events(/period/:period)', to: 'events#index', as: :events_period
```

My tag filtering uses the `tag_path` to submit itself:

```
<%= form_tag tag_path, method: :post, do %>
```

Both filtering actions are dealt with by the `index` action in the `EventsController`.

What I want to do is remember the filtering of `period` while filtering for `tags`. In other words, when the url is `/period/past` and the `meh` tag is selected, I would like to apply both filtering options.

Could I submit the form to the current url or should I change the route of `tag_path` to include the `period` filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add hidden `period` field to your tag form and fill it with your current filtering options. After that you'll get you filtering options in params[:period] in controller.
This approach doesn't require to change your routes.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but I used to use the `overwrite_params` options on `url_for`. So if you're on a given page you can have a link use the same page with the same parameters as are currently present, and only change the params you want changed. However that seems to have been deprecated in Rails 3. But you can still do it manually like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Add the meh filter', url_for(params.merge(tag_name: 'meh')) %>
```